# Efficient character processing of NSString

Tags: objective-c, swift, performance, cocoa, nsstring

I need to do some character processing of huge strings in Cocoa (from Objective-C or Swift), where:

- The input string passed in an `NSString` has n characters
- The result should be returned in an `NSString`
- It's OK to make simplifying assumptions on the characters in the string. I mean we can assume they are all ASCII, or all single code unit UTF8, or even all `unichar` (so as to make indexing and length computation O(1))

For the sake of the example, let's say the processing is a rot13 obfuscation.

I want to do it space and time efficiently:

- I want to get a mutable buffer of characters from the source string (probably a copy)
- I want to alter that buffer in place
- I want to return the altered buffer in a constructed `NSString` without doing another copy.

I want space complexity ≤ 2*n+ O(1).

I want time complexity O(n) - with as small a constant as possible.

The `NSString` API allows for that easily, but is too inefficient, with plenty of back and forth conversion from character to string. I am shooting for C-level efficient processing of characters here.

The `NSString` API also allows to get a buffer of character with methods such as `dataUsingEncoding:` or `UTF8String`. But I can't find a way to use the API where I copy the characters for processing no more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate a buffer of `unichar`. Copy into the buffer w/ `getCharacters(range:)`. Manipulate. Convert back using `init(charactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:)`.

`unichar` is UTF-16. If you're willing to assume that nothing require surrogate characters (for example, if you assume it's ASCII), then you can just allocate your buffer based on `length` (it'll be 2 * length). If you want to be more flexible, but still O(1) at the cost of 2-3x memory requirement, then use `maximumLengthOfBytes`. If you want to be more flexible, but are willing to accept an O(n) step (I assume you aren't), then use `lengthOfBytes`.

It is somewhat common for `NSString` to be stored internally as UTF-16, so this tends to be a very fast conversion. That said, if you have enough knowledge about your strings, and are willing to write additional code to manipulate encodings directly, then look at `fastestEncoding`.

Comment: to be more precise, `fastestEncoding ` can be then used with the method `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:`. Thanks for the answer